# Angularjs + Python Eve Token based authentication

Tags: angularjs, eve, satellizer

I am currently implementing a auth APIs for python EVE.

There are quite a few projects around token based auth in Angularjs notably https://github.com/sahat/satellizer

My question is, How could I integrate satellizer with Python Eve?

Comment: the bower didn't work for you?

Comment: which bower package you are talking here?